# Why functions differentiable at a given point is a vector space?

Tags: calculus

I'm following Apostol's book volume II and in page 5 in an example of vector spaces, the example 9 says:"The set of all functions differentiable at a given point". Why is that an example of that? How do I prove it? Would it actually work for an interval as well?

Comment: What conditions do you have to check?

Comment: Try to show that the sum of differentiable functions is again differentiable and that multiplying a differentiable function by a scalar (a real or complex number) makes it again a differentiable number.

Comment: All the axioms of Vector spaces and I'll try to figure out about your idea